Swiper JS only center active slide
I have a slider where i show multiple slides per view.
I want to show 1.5 slides per view.
When i do this the active slide aligns left.
If i add the parameter centeredSlides then all my slides are in the center.
What i want to achieve is:
Frist slide aligns left.
Second slide (when active) aligns in the middle.
Last slide aligns right.
Is this possible with Swiper or does anyone know any other slider where i can achieve this with?
I prefer sliders working with jQuery.
Examples:

1st slide
2nd slide
last slide


Have you tried with centeredSlidesBounds: true?
According to Swiper's docs, that seems to achive what you're looking for:

If true, then active slide will be centered without adding gaps at the
beginning and end of slider. Required centeredSlides: true. Not
intended to be used with loop or pagination

